# Install to a RAID 0 array from Windows

Tags: installation, nvidia, wubi, raid

I have an ASUS MB with an NVIDIA RAID 0 array set up as my boot disc with 200Gb unformatted ready for Ubuntu.  Will WUBI install onto this?

Answer (score 1):

**If you want to install from windows**, you can go ahead and do so. But you will have to **assemble the raid on a live CD** and **install grub to a valid boot-able partition**.

Now, If i remember correctly, the common **"fakeraids"**(the kind you enable in the bios) have a boot partition for assembly and for windows to use.
So you should be able to select that.
You can also use a separate drive **Like a USB**

Of course.. I could be wrong.